# Confusion over wording of a question in topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]In the following question 2.2.8 in the attached image:

Let $B\subset int D^{2}$ be a disk.  Show that there is a point $x\in\partial{B}$ such that the radial line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ starting at $x$ ending at the point of distance 1 from the origin intersects $\partial{B}$ and $S^1$ in precisely one point each (a radial line segment is a line segment that when extended contains the origin).  Show that there must be at least two such points.

I am being ask to show that there are two different points say, x and y both belonging to $\partial{B}$.
  I am confused with the wording of the question.  The condition in the question states that "...the radial line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the point $x$ and ending at the point of distance 1 from the origin intersect the boundary of $B$ and the circle in precisely one point each."  I am uncertain as to the last bit of the sentence when I look over the accompanied diagram.  When it says "precisely one point each", in the illustration, the subset shown is a region completely contain within the disc $D^2$.  The radial line segment from the origin $O_2$ to the boundary of $D^2$ at a distance 1, intersects $B$ at two different points, one of them being point $x.$ Am I to understand it as follows, given a region $M$ which is a subset of $D^2$, choose a point $w$ on the boundary of $M$ and the radial line with a length of 1 from the center of the disc will intersect the point $w$ and also some point $z$ on the boundary of $D^2$. It doesn't matter if the said radial line segment intersect any other boundary point belonging to $M$ has not been chosen.

If anyone can help with to clarify the geometric situation of the question, it will much be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here when the author calls the radial line segment from $x$ is only the non-dotted part of the line in the picture. It is the segment that *starts* at $x$, and follows the radial direction (so from the origin), and then stops when it hits the circle.

Comment: you mean the radial line segment is in the same direction  as the one which it emanates from the origin and the non dotted portion from point $x$ to the boundary of $D^2$ or in this case $S^1$.  Since the non dotted line segment intercepts the boundary of the $S^1$ and the region $M$ respectively at only one point each. That is what the condition is saying.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Captain Lama is correct. Regarding a possible solution, I could think of two ideas.

(a). Find a circle $C$ with smallest possible radius containing $B$. Then $C$ and $B$ will intersect in at least two points (as illustrated by the case when $B$ is the closed region bounded by an ellipse).

(b) There are infinitely many points as sought. For any non-zero point $p\in B$ take a line segment starting at the origin, going through $p$, and keep going till a point $q$ on $S^1$ is reached (it will be $q=\frac p{|p|}$). Going from $p$ to $q$ there will be a "last point" in $B$, on the line segment $pq$. That last point $x$ will have the required property.

Which just raises the question again, what did the author mean, and why only two such points (and not infinitely many)? But I cannot think of a different interpretation than the one already given in the answer by Captain Lama.

Edit. Responding to the comment below, your interpretation is a bit confusing to me since for no apparent reason you introduce a region $M$ (why not work with $B$ which has already been introduced by the author). Then you seem to suggest (in your question) that you could pick an arbitrary point $w$ on the boundary of $M$, and consider the radial line from the origin, through $w$ and to some point $z$ on the boundary of $D^2$. Then you say:
"It doesn't matter if the said radial line segment intersect any other boundary point belonging to $M$ has not been chosen."
In my opinion, it does matter 
(aside from my difficulties interpreting what you say in quoted sentence, its grammar feels a bit off). 
In my answer I suggest that $x$ must be "the last" point of this intersection (in direction starting at the origin). See the enclosed picture, where $w$ does not qualify, but $x$ does.

[image: w does not qualify, but x does]

Comment: in my response to Captain Lama, is my interpretation correct?  I tried emailing the author of the text, but did not get any email response.

Comment: @SethMai I edited my answer trying to address your comment

Comment: thank you for your write up.  My apologies for the late reply.  I have been feeling under the weather.  Sorry about the way I am describing things.  I am still a bit confused over the phrase by what the author means "precisely one point each: with reference to what precise geometric situation. 

How about I use the following two examples in terms of coordinates.  
(1)  Suppose I have two concentric unit circles, the larger one has a radius of 1 and the smaller one has a radius of 1/2.  I let $x$ be the point (0,1/2)...

Comment: ...and extended it to the origin $O_2$ which is the non dotted line portion.  (2) Given a unit circle of radius 1 and another circle that is subset of the unit circle with origin at (0,1/2), radius 1/6 and points of diameter at coordinate (0,1/3) and (0, 2/3).  I let $x$ to be at (0,2/3) and extend it to (0,1).  This will be the dotted portion of the radial line segment.  If extending (the dotted line portion) to the other direction, It goes from (0,2/3) to the origin but it also intercepts the point (0,1/3).  From both geometric situations, (2) is confusing me, because it seems that...

Comment: ...the radial line segment hits the subset of the unit circle at two different points, one at $x=(0,2/3)$ and another one at (0,1/3) which is consider to be arbitrary.  I am having trouble reconciling with the statement "precisely at one point each."

Comment: @SethMai A radial segment lies on a line that goes through the origin. The author means start at $x$ and *go away* from the origin,*opposite* the origin,till you hit the unit circle at some $y$. The line segment $xy$ intersects $\partial B$ at exactly one point, namely $x$,and intersects $S^1$ in exactly one point, $y$. In my picture, starting at $w$ going away from the origin,intersect $\partial B$ twice,at $w$ and $x$, so $w$ no good. In your example, start at $(0,2/3)$, don't go to the origin, go away from the origin, intersect small circle at $(0,2/3)$ only, and unit circle at $(0,1)$ only

Comment: thank you for clearing that up.  That is what I thought you mean actually.  It is my fault that I did not use coordinates in my examples.  Thank you so kindly very much for your patience.

Comment: @SethMai You are very welcome!